# How to open two urls in one link with html in email?

Tags: html, email, url

I want to create a link which opens two urls in email.

I tried to use JavaScript to do it but JavaScript is disabled in email:

```
<a id="test" href="#"> Click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
   window.open("http://www.google.com",'_blank');
   window.open("http://www.yahoo.com",'_blank');
}
</script>
```

How to do it using html?

Thanks.

Comment: create 2 hidden ahref, set the value using js and then click on them using js or jquery

Comment: JS is disabled.

Comment: any particular reason for disabling that, nothing related JS will work then.

Comment: I guess it's due to security issue.

Comment: I have included my js script. Any other methods?

Comment: you cannot play around with HTML DOM without using js/jquery. Share the exact requirement, we might be able to share a possible solution.

Comment: No other requirement, just want to do it in email without blocked.